# Can I make one editText look like four

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I wanna make those `editText` fields make look still like this, but actually it will be only one `editText`

I've tried to use them as four, but it's not a proper way as I understand

[Current and required look of layout, in red "circle" editText fields I mentioned before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJuiE.png)

Comment: as far as I know, this is not possible without using several edit texts

Comment: Is there any problem to have 4 individual `EditText` for your design? Cause I think you shouldn't use any 3rd party `library` for this silly and easy design concept.

Comment: @Saadat I've tried to use 4 but at some point UX suffers. Like when I try to delete all in one hold of delete button. Or when I try autofill with Google. So I think it's not a correct way to use 4 individually.

Comment: What you can't do with XML can be done programatically. Good luck!

Comment: @Shigure yes, you can do it programatically. If you have enough time and courage to do it programatically, if not use the libraries as answered below.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your requirement by using [this library](https://github.com/ChaosLeung/PinView).

Put this in your dependencies `implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'`
and use this code in your layout

```xml
<com.chaos.view.PinView
    android:id="@+id/firstPinView"
    style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:hint="Hint."
    android:inputType="text"
    android:itemBackground="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/text_colors"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:cursorColor="@color/line_selected"
    app:cursorWidth="2dp"
    app:hideLineWhenFilled="true"
    app:itemCount="5"
    app:itemHeight="48dp"
    app:itemRadius="4dp"
    app:itemSpacing="0dp"
    app:itemWidth="48dp"
    app:lineColor="@color/line_colors"
    app:lineWidth="2dp"
    app:viewType="rectangle" />
```

For more details see their [docs](https://github.com/ChaosLeung/PinView#java)

Comment: there is also another good library https://github.com/shiburagi/BlockEditText

Comment: although i dont disagree with your answer, is there really a point for adding a library for something you can do with android itself (4 edit texts) ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody according to question, she has tried 4 edit texts. She is asking for more proper way.

Comment: yes i understand that and i'm not disagreeing with your answer, i'm simply asking if it's worth adding a third party library to achieve this ?

Comment: I need a way to implement it without libraries. I guess only way for it just put a mask above `editText`. and divide text with spaces